# When managing multiple inputs in React

Tags: reactjs, input, use-state

```
    const [state, setState]=useState({
        value:0,
        value2:0
    });

    const onChange1=()=>{
        setState({
            ...state,
            value:5
        });
    };
    const onChange2=()=>{
        setState({
            ...state,
            value2:10
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>value:{state.value}</div>
            <div>value2:{state.value2}</div>
            <button onChange={onChange1}>value</button>
            <button onChange={onChange2}>value2</button>
        </div>
        
    );
```

I want to manage value1 and value2 differently depending on the button. However, I am not used to managing multiple inputs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? Are you having problems with the current code?

Comment: Yes, the value does not change even when I press the button @CertainPerformance

Comment: Describe your question very well. we can't help you without knowing the problem you are facing. describe your problem.

Comment: When I press the first button, the value will change to 5, and when I press the second button, value2 will change to 10, but it does not change. Help me please..i dont know what my problem is... @MichaleRezene

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason your code is not working is that you used `onChange` method. use `onClick` instead. You usually use `onChange` in `input`.

Comment: Thank you. But why does onChange not work and onClick works?

Comment: because it is a button. you don't change fields on button you just click a button but when it comes to inputs you change something on the input by writing something  that is why we use onChange on input. It actually doesn't make sense to say onChange for a button because you click a button you don't change a button. Hope you understand it...

Comment: Thank you. I missed something too basic. Thanks to you, I learn a lot!

Comment: it would be a good habit to verify the answer you get so that other people can know which the right answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Use an onClick() instead of onChange() and this will work how you have it set up:
https://repl.it/repls/LankyBleakConstants#src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will not forget your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
const [state, setState]=useState({
        value:0,
        value2:0
    });

    const onChange1= ()=>{
        setState((prevState)=> ({
            ...prevState,
            value:5
        }));
    };
    const onChange2= ()=>{
        setState((prevState)=> ({
            ...prevState,
            value2:10
        }));
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div>value:{state.value}</div>
            <div>value2:{state.value2}</div>
            <button onClick={onChange1}>value</button>
            <button onClick={onChange2}>value2</button>
        </div>
        
    );
```

Comment: Thank you. One more question, can I specify any variable instead of prevState?